# Spring WS annotated endpoint

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-ws

I have to replace the deprecated class `AbstractMarshallingPayloadEndpoin`t from springws 2.0. which my class was extending and overriding the `invokeInternal` method as below.

Example :

```
public class UpdateUserEndpoint extends AbstractMarshallingPayloadEndpoint {

    @Override
    protected Object invokeInternal(Object request){
    //MY BUSINESS LOGIC here.
    }
}
```

I am trying to replace my class with endpoint annotation.

```
@PayloadRoot(localPart = "MyRequest", namespace = "MyNamespace")
public MyResponse updateUser(MyRequest request) { ... }
```

I am ending up with exception while the server startup with a `BeanCreationException`:
I use Castor marshaller and unmarshaller in mapping.
Need some thoughts to proceed in a right way.

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'updateUserEndpoint' defined in class path resource [spring/wsContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'marshaller' of bean class [com.test.UpdateUserEndpoint]: Bean property 'marshaller' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Comment: Please add the fullstack to your post, not as a comment. Also if you read the stacktrace you will see that your bean doesn't have the desired property. Which is true as you should be wiring the marshaller to the handler or mapper. Please add your configuration also (and please remember to format it correctly!).